# Space occupied by array of struct

Tags: c, memory-alignment

A question I have on Problem 3.44 of the book *Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective* (3rd edition (6 October 2015)) on data alignment.

The problem:

> For each of the following structure declarations, determine the offset of each feild, the total size of the structure, for 8-bit alignment:

```c
struct P1 {short i; int c; int *j; short *d}
...
struct P4 {char w[16]; char *c[2]}
struct P5 {struct P4 a[2]; struct P1 t}
```

Answer given in the book:

- struct P1:

| i | c | j | d | total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2 | 6 | 14 | 16 |

- struct P4:

| w | c | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 16 | 32 |

- struct P5:

| a | t | total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 24 | 40 |

What I don't get is why did `struct P4 a[2]` in `P5` only takes 24 bytes?
Since `P5.a` is an array of `P4` of size 2, shouldn't it occupy `2 * 32 (total size of P4)` bytes?

---

To make sure I quote the book correctly, attaching the screenshots below:
[image]
[image]

Comment: When was that book released? It was a very long time ago that alignment was typically only two bytes. The likely offsets for e.g. `P1` would be something like `4` and `8` for the `c` and `j` variables, then on a 64-bit system the offset for `d` would be `16` (or `12` for a 32-bit system). The size would then probably be `24` (with padding at the end for a 32-bit system).

Comment: And *very* related: [Why isn't sizeof for a struct equal to the sum of sizeof of each member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member)

Comment: Also the book seems to have some major problems: Besides that it says the pointer `j` is 8 bytes, it also tell that the pointer `d` is *two* bytes. That doesn't match. And of course the problem with `P4` which just can't be 12 bytes large, the `w` member in that structure is 16 bytes on its own. Have you looked online to see if there's some [errata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erratum) for the book?

Comment: "What I don't get is why..." Does that mean, you understand why `P1` is only 16 bytes? I don't.

Comment: The book is wrong.

Comment: It isn't unreasonable that a book which was released 20 years ago and is currently on the 3rd edition should have been proof-read better. Again, I think a SO black list / hall of shame of anti-recommendations would be helpful to mankind.

Comment: OT: The posted code has several syntax errors but perhaps it's not 100% as it is in the book

Comment: In that `P1` struct it seems that `d` should actually be `short` instead of `short*`.

Comment: A publication error in a STEM book! Stop presses!! This is NEWS!!! // sarcasm off

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Indeed, here are the [errata for this book](https://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/errata.html), but there is no mention of the errors in this problem solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- P1 is wrong. In case `int* j` occupies 8 bytes, then on any known real-world computer with 64 bit addressing, `short* d` will also occupy 8 bytes. For a total of 22 bytes, assuming no padding was inserted after `i`, which is unlikely. In case padding is inserted, the total size would be 24 bytes.

  On a real-world 64 bit system, the struct layout would be:

  ```
  short  i  size: 2   offset:  0
  int    c  size: 4   offset:  4
  int*   j  size: 8   offset:  8
  short* d  size: 8   offset: 16
  ```
- > What I don't get is why did struct P4 a[2] in P5 only takes 24 bytes?

  It doesn't. `P4` = 32 bytes, no padding. 2 * 32 = 64 bytes. `P5` will be 64 + 24 = 88 bytes.

If you are quoting the book correctly, then evidently it has not been proof-read from the programmer's perspective...

Comment: I wrote this little test program yesterday when answering a similar question: https://godbolt.org/z/3YvYrExoY. Just edit the "X macro" list. In case of array members you might have to typedef them in advance.

Comment: That same code modded for `P5`: https://godbolt.org/z/Krhvf488e

Answer (score 5):

You have a copy of the Global Edition of CS:APP3e.

As we state in the [errata web page](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/errata.html):

> **Note on the Global Edition:** Unfortunately, the publisher arranged for
> the generation of a different set of practice and homework problems in
> the global edition. The person doing this didn't do a very good job,
> and so these problems and their solutions have many errors. We have
> not created an errata for this edition.

This is one of the many problems that got messed up.

Comment: But the book is on the **third** edition and it's been out for **twenty** years. Why wasn't this corrected some decade ago?

Comment: Anyway, "the book is wrong" doesn't answer the question. This is a technical Q&A site, answers are supposed to answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

A code to test: (Gives the occupation in structure, not the size).

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct P1
{
    short i;
    int c;
    int *j;
    short *d;
    long long end[];
};

struct P4
{
    char w[16];
    char *c[2];
    long long end[];
};

struct P5
{
    struct P4 a[2];
    struct P1 t;
    long long end[];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct P1 p1;
    printf("size of p1 : %zu\n", sizeof(p1));    
    printf("short i : %zu\n", (size_t)&p1.c - (size_t)&p1.i);
    printf("int c : %zu\n", (size_t)&p1.j - (size_t)&p1.c);
    printf("int *j : %zu\n", (size_t)&p1.d - (size_t)&p1.j);
    printf("short *d : %zu\n", (size_t)&p1.end - (size_t)&p1.d);

    struct P4 p4;
    printf("\nsize of p4 : %zu\n", sizeof(p4));
    printf("char w[16] : %zu\n", (size_t)&p4.c - (size_t)&p4.w);
    printf("char *c[2] : %zu\n", (size_t)&p4.end - (size_t)&p4.c);

    struct P5 p5;
    printf("\nsize of p5 : %zu\n", sizeof(p5));
    printf("struct P4 a[2] : %zu\n", (size_t)&p5.t - (size_t)&p5.a);
    printf("struct P1 t : %zu\n", (size_t)&p5.end - (size_t)&p5.t);

    return 0;
}
```

- The flexible member array is just to mark the end.

Following Gerhardh's remark, code with offsetof.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stddef.h>

struct P1
{
    short i;
    int c;
    int *j;
    short d;
    long long end[];
};

int main(void)
{
    struct P1 p1;
    printf("                   Offset        Size    Occupation\n");
    printf("short i  : %12zu %12zu %12zu\n", offsetof(struct P1, i), sizeof(p1.i), offsetof(struct P1, c));
    printf("int c    : %12zu %12zu %12zu\n", offsetof(struct P1, c), sizeof(p1.c), offsetof(struct P1, j)-offsetof(struct P1, c));
    printf("int *j   : %12zu %12zu %12zu\n", offsetof(struct P1, j), sizeof(p1.j), offsetof(struct P1, d)-offsetof(struct P1, j));
    printf("short *d : %12zu %12zu %12zu\n", offsetof(struct P1, d), sizeof(p1.d), offsetof(struct P1, end)-offsetof(struct P1, d));
    printf("end      : %12zu \n", offsetof(struct P1, end));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you aware of the `offsetof` macro?

Comment: I've forgotten!